# Write in an already opened Excel workbook from Powerpoint Slide

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to write in an already manually opened workbook using VBA from my PowerPoint presentation.

Using CreateObject and then Workbook.Open it opens a new instance of the file.
I'm trying to use GetObject as found in several examples over the web.

Here's my code :

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkbook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = Trueme
Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\Suivi individuel.xlsx", True, False)
xlWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C14").Value = "Hello"

SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide nextSlide
```

I've tried:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkbook As Object

Set xlWorkbook = GetObject(ActivePresentation.Path & "\Suivi individuel.xlsx", "Excel.Application")

xlWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C14").Value = "Hello"

SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide nextSlide
```

It says runtime error 432: File Name or Class Name not found during automation operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkbook As Object

Set xlWorkbook = GetObject(ActivePresentation.Path & "\Suivi individuel.xlsx")
```

If you just want to get an open instance of Excel then

```
Set xlApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
```

Wrap that in an error handler if there's a chance Excel might not be open

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288902

Comment: Ok thanks it works ! And what should i do if i don't know the filename and just want the first excel workbook open then?